# Time-Dependent Moments of General SDEs

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

*Context:* In some lecture slides for a class I am taking, we are given the equations

$$d\langle  x \rangle = \langle dx \rangle$$
$$d\langle x^2 \rangle = \langle 2\,x\,dx \rangle + \langle \frac{1}{2}\,(dx)^2 \rangle$$

and I am wondering the justifications for these equations.

More generally, consider and SDE of the form

$$ dx = a\left(t,\ x\right)\,dt + \sigma\left(t,\ x\right)\,dW $$

Is there a closed-form equation for $d\langle f\left(t,\ x\right)\rangle$ for some general $f(t,\ x)$? Possibly in terms of $\langle df\left(t,\ x\right) \rangle$?

---

My initial thought is to use Ito's formula

$$d f\left(t,\ x\right) = \left(\partial_t f + a(t,\ x)\,\partial_x f + \frac{1}{2}b(t,\ x)\,\partial_x^2 f\right)\,dt + b(t,\ x)\,\partial_x f\,dW$$

which leads to an equation for $\langle d f(t,\ x) \rangle$. However, I don't know how the differential operator $d$ interacts with the ensemble average $\langle \cdot \rangle$.

Comment: Your 'average' is an expected value. If you take the expectation of the rhs of your results after applying Ito's formula, you get: $\mathbb E \left(d f\left(t,\ x\right)\right) = \left(\partial_t f + a(t,\ x)\,\partial_x f + \frac{1}{2}b(t,\ x)\,\partial_x^2 f\right)\,dt$.

Comment: @GáborPálovics

Okay, that makes sense. How does that lead to an equation for $d[\mathbb{E}(f(t, x))]$?

Comment: The value of $\mathbb E(f(t,x))$ is a deterministic function of $t$, you can differentiate it to get what you need, however it's not trivial to get this expected value. For example in case of $a=x \cdot a_0$ and $\sigma = x \cdot \sigma_0$ and $f(x, t) = x$, you have $x_t = x_0 \cdot e^{\left(a_0 - \frac12 \sigma_0^2\right)t} \cdot e^{\sigma_0 W_t} \implies \mathbb E(f(x, t)) = \mathbb E x_t = x_0 \cdot e^{a_0 t} \implies d \mathbb E(f(x, t)) = x_0 a_0 e^{a_0 t} dt$

Comment: In the above case $\mathbb E (df) = \mathbb E dx_t = \mathbb E (a_0 x_t dt) = x_0 a_0 e^{a_0 t}dt$

Comment: **Note:** in my first comment I left out the expectation on the r.h.s.